# BASH Check if [process] is running, recheck every hour

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop

I have `shred` running in the background on 16 drives. I would like to have a bash script that checks the process `pidof shred` every hour. If the process doesn't show, then `echo "Shredding Completed...` else `echo "Shredding Running..."`

This is what I have right now, when `shred` is not running it will echo `"Shredding Completed..."` but if it is running the script exits out.

```
while :
do
if pidof shred > : && break
then
    echo "Shredding Running..."
    sleep 60m
else
    echo "Shredding Completed..."
    exit
fi

done
```

THank you

FIXED: Retarded me, I took out `&& break` and it works! lol

Answer (score 1):

Write to `/dev/null` instead of `:` and don't `break` the loop every time you do so:

```
while :
do
  if pidof shred > /dev/null
  then
      echo "Shredding Running..."
      sleep 60m
  else
      echo "Shredding Completed..."
      exit
  fi 
done
```

The better way of doing this is simply:

```
while pidof shred > /dev/null
do
  echo "Shred running..."
  sleep 60m
done
echo "Done"
```

Also note that [shred is not more secure](http://privazer.com/overwriting_hard_drive_data.The_great_controversy.pdf), than a simple `dd if=/dev/zero of=device bs=4M`.

Comment: Yeah, I figure the `break` part out lol. I thought `:` was the same thing as `/dev/null`?

Comment: `:` is a file called `:`. `ls -l :` in the dir where you ran this. When executed it's also a synonym for the `true` command.

Comment: Thank you, I will use that simple way. I know about the shred vs. dd thing. Just using shred with one random pass then zero out the drive. It's not my call, trust me.